# Java- Passing unknown DAO

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I created a common method in which I will pass a DAO but it will not be a one DAO. Like i will be passing not only StudentDao but also TeachersDao and ClubsDao.

Originally, this is my method:

```
    public static String getSomething(StudentDao, String id){

        Properties proFind = new Properties();
        proFind.put(StudentDao.ID, id);

        dao.select(proFind).get(0);

        return somethingINeed;
    }
```

But then I've decided that to use only one method, make it something generic..
Somthing like this:

```
    public static <T> String getSomething(Class<T> dao, String id){

        Properties proFind = new Properties();
        proFind.put(StudentDao.ID, id);

        dao.select(proFind).get(0);

        return somethingINeed;
    }
```

but this is not correct.

So my objective is to pass any Dao in that method.
Did i miss something in java? 
Any idea or enlightenment is greatly appreciated.

[EDIT]

All my Daos extends Dao which is and interface.
My concern is just this method in which how I can use any Dao.
The attributes used can be found in the interface Dao also.

Comment: Isn't this a bit backwards? Shouldn't your business code contain something like `studentDAO.getStudentById(id);` and then work with that (and possibly other DAOs as well, such as getting teachers and their students).

Comment: if inside getSomething you are going to use same method of all dao like get the select method of dao then use programming to interface option

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Kayaman's comment above.

Your service/business tier should be interfacing with multiple DAOs to perform CRUD operations on different entities e.g. Student, Teacher.

```
public class MyService {

    private StudentDao studentDao;
    private TeacherDao teacherDao;

    // Daos injected

    public Student findStudent(Long id) {
        return this.studentDao.find(id);
    }

    // Other methods involving students or teachers
}
```

Trying to have one generic DAO is cumbersome and not good design in my opinion.

If you have a base DAO and base entity classes, you can still push a lot of the boilerplate CRUD code into the base classes. When I first started using DAOs, I found the following article very useful: [Don't repeat the DAO!](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-genericdao/)

Answer (score 0):

thats why java created Interface[enter link description here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) or [Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

just create a DAO interface or base class and change your method to

public static String getSomething(Dao dao, String id)

Comment: How do you know a String is always returned?

Comment: i dont, i just suggested a solution with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
public static String getSomething(Object dao, String id){

if(dao instanceOf StudentDao){
 // do your code
 }
else if(dao instanceOf AnotherDao){
 // do your code
 }
```

and so on.............